# Определить высоту активного задать эту высоту элементу

Tags: jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Блоки BLOCK#1 и BLOCK#2 имеют ширину 100%.
Как мне для блока BLOCK#1 автоматически задавать высоту с размер видимого окна браузера (красная линия) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html, body, .block-1 {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.block-1 {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class=block-1>Первый</div>
<div class=block-2>Второй</div>
```

Comment: Мне надо с помощью jquery определять размер блока для баннера. Помимо этого блока будут ещё элементы.

Comment: Данный способ, оказывается, прекрасно подошёл.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.block-1 {
  height: 100vh;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class=block-1>Первый</div>
<div class=block-2>Второй</div>
```